# Azure App service has 230 seconds timeout, does background processing continue?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a function that sends emails to a list of clients, this usually goes on longer than the 230 second timeout for azure functions, my question is, will this function continue to send emails to clients after the response timeout? If so is there anyway to check if it is completed?

Comment: Have you tested how it behaves after function timeout?

Answer (score 0):

So app service and http azure function sits behind [Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds) which will have 230 timeout. You can tune but its wrong to do it.

I think reasonable solution here would be to change design.

1. Create `api/start` endpoint which will send event to lets say blob queue (its cheap)
2. Create [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue) which listen to that queue and start processing. Also design it this way that it sends email in batch lets say 100 at a time and if you need to send more send same event back to queue with offset so next time your AF pick up from where it left. When complete write result to azure blob table for instance with id and status complete
3. Create `api/status` which will return you status by id
4. On frontend call `api/start`, it will return you new id then ping every 5 seconds your `api/status/ID` and see if job is done

PS. your http job will continue but it will hit 5 minutes azure function timeout if you haven't modify [default timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout)

Comment: Thanks, I am planning to redesign it, I will try to see how I can implement it like you suggested. I just sent emails out today, and was wondering if they were sent. We are on the app service plan and its modified to unlimited so it shouldn't timeout.

Comment: @EamonnElGendy well if you use sendgrid or something you can check there too. Secondly what i do for similar things in my project. Email which i need to trace will be dumbed to private container in blob storage.

Comment: @EamonnElGendy in addition you probably use application insights so that would be other place to check

Comment: The application insights seems to only show the emailjob runs that had a successful response but not the ones that reached 230 + seconds. I will check SendGrid though!